custom css for global styles not applying
I am using StartFit theme on wordpress. When I add custom css to apply to h1 or h2, for example, the custom styling is not applying. The styling is only applying when I use specific classes for the wordpress elements e.g:
h2.wp-block-post-title {color: #F00700;}

The above code works. But this does not work:
h2 {color: #F00700;}

I am able to change the global styles by using the 'styles' section which is built into the theme. But I want to be able to change global styles using the additional CSS, and am not sure why it is not applying.

Are you sure that it isn't being applied, or is it being applied and then overwritten by more specific rules? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Your CSS is likely being overwritten by the WordPress CSS. To check this, open your developer tools (f12 or right click->inspect element), and find the element you're trying to style. In the styles tab in the developer tools, scroll to see all of the CSS blocks that apply to your element.
Likely, your custom CSS block will be overridden. In the developer tools, your CSS styles will be crossed out with a strikethrough.
In CSS, if there are multiple attempts to set the same attribute on the same element, one attribute will override the other. To prioritize the attribute you want to apply, use the !important tag. An attribute tagged !important will override other styles.
E.g:
h2 {color: #F00700 !important;}

Be wary that applying a style to all h2 may not be what you want. You likely want to be more selective when applying the custom style -- you should instead identify a class of h2s that you want to style, and then style those accordingly.
